# Use Ubuntu with Nvidia GeForce 240M

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, nouveau, nvidia-geforce

I have Fujitsu Amilo notebook with Nvidia GeForce 240M.
I have trying to install clear LTS Ubuntu 18, Ubuntu 20 and Ubuntu 22
None of them can start graphical environment after installation with errors from nouveau like "DRM lock" or completaly freezing I can only boot with nomodeset and as result fallback to vesa driver. As I can learn, nouveau driver is not supporting Nvidia GeForce GT 240M video card.

All this points me to proprietary Nvidia drivers. Nvidia site told me that they have driver [LINUX X64 (AMD64/EM64T) DISPLAY DRIVER Version:    340.108](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/156163/en-us) which contains `GeForce GT 240M` in SUPPORTED PRODUCTS section.

That driver is detected as the compatible one but can not be installed nor from "Additional drivers" interface not from dowloaded .run file on Ubuntu 20.04 and Ubuntu 22.04 because of incompatible kernel version.
I have fount two solutions

1. Nvidia-legacy 340 package from Butterfly [~kelebek333 / nvidia-legacy](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy)
2. Patch for newer kernels in [inttf NVIDIA 340.xx](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2020/inttf-nvidia-patcher/)

Both not help with pretty same result: Gnome not started with black screen and mouse pointer in the center of right-bottom quarter of the screen.

Only for Ubuntu 18.04 I can successfully install proprietary driver without patching but still unable to make it work and X is not starting.

In some configurations I'm able to press Alt+F2 and login into console from that black screen, in other not, but I can press power on button and system begin poweroff process, in other it just freezes.

I'm almost give up trying after whole **week** of unsuccessful experiments and considering to install Offtopic7 OS :(

Can someone please confirm me that it is really possible to run Nvidia GeForce GT 240M video card on one of Ubuntus 18+ versions (Or may be older?) with opensource or propriepary drivers?

Or can you please help me to troubleshot the problem, may be I'm missing something?

For example, does it enough to run `sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'` to return back to nouveau driver and try to install other driver version from scratch or there can remains some things which can interfere with other installation?

Should I install dkms headers (or something like that, don't remember correctly) which driver installation ask me to install at the end to make it possible to install new kernel (I'm not planning to do that).

Should I install [CUDA Toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Ubuntu) at all to just use browser and video playback?

I'm really stuck and will appreciate any bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue as my Nvidia nvs160 is only supported by 340 legacy drivers.

Steps I do on Debian 11:

- Clean Install
- Change sources.list to point to Debian 10
- sudo apt update
- Install kernel 4.19 series from Debian 10
- Restart machine and on grub I choose 4.19 kernel
- Remove 5.10 Kernel
- Install nvidia drivers 340
- Pin nvidia drivers and kernel (I use first option: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto)
- Revert sources.list to point to Debian 11
- Everything works fine from now on

On Ubuntu 20.04 we have more than one kernel option to use, you can install 5.4, reboot and remove newer kernels, by doing so you can install nvidia 340 drivers. On Ubuntu 22.04 you can try to revert sources.list of Ubuntu 20.04 install kernel and 340 driver then go back to sources.list of ubuntu 22.04.

Be aware that we upgrade kernel not just for more hardware support but for security updates too, in my setups if I find that a security update is needed/urgent I will have to update my old kernel version and if this happens I will probably have to reinstall. Revert sources.list should work but this is not always an option, after you install things and starts using the system reverting shows a lot of errors and broken package etc.

Hope this helps.

Kind Recards,

Carlos Adriano Portes

Comment: Thanks for sharing, i will try.

Comment: You are welcome!